# How to clear Sort in Excel 2007

Tags: excel

I put filters in some columns with numeric values and then used the "Sort Smallest to Largest" feature in one column. Excel sorts and changes the icon in the filter. How do I clean this sort? The sort option is inside the filter button (in the cell) but it seems that is not possible to clean the sort: the "Clean Filter From ..." is not enabled and the only way is to undo.

I want to sort, change data and sort back, and there is no other column that could be sorted to get back to the initial state.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me was `CTRL+Z`, i.e., `undo`. I must mention that I was just doing a simple sorting without actually filtering. `clear` option in `Editing` is quite redundant for "unsorting" in that it just removes the sort but doesn't re-order the rows to original state.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a temporary new column with sequential numbering, then ordenate the whole worksheet using the desired column, and then filter back using the temporary ordinated column.

Comment: I was afraid to read that :( I don't want to do this, I will sort and add/remove lines all the time. Does excel suck so much that it cannot do this for me, internally?

Comment: @Roberto, it doesn't require much effort to adjust your filter after you've edited a few lines. If it bothers you that much, you could create a macro that instantly turns on that filter, so it's filtered at the touch of a button.

Comment: its really suck, I have 1000 rows that I sorted them using the "fillter options" without being aware that I can't undo that, and now I can't clear the sort to revert them to their original status!!!!

Comment: JIPS' answer resolves this.  I use it all the time; Alt + H, S, C.  Home, Sort & Filter, Clear.  Problem solved.  If your original order isn't resortable (which would be pretty weird if you actually wanted it that way...), then you could create a column of row number values, then resort by that column when you're done.  Do it all in one macro and it's an easy one-step process.

Answer (score 16):

After using the filtering and sorting combination it's possible to reset those filters, in order to display the worksheet's initial state, by selecting the "Clear" function from the ribbon:

Home/Editing - Sort & Filter/Clear

Note that this does not return a table to it's original/initial sort order, but it does remove all filters and gets rid of any sort arrows in the table header.

*Also valid for Excel 2010

Comment: With Excel 2013, you can go in "data' tab, then open the "sort" menu, then remove irrelevant columns.

Comment: While this does clear the filter, unfortunately it does not revert to worksheet's initial state: i.e. I sort a column in filter, clear the filter and rows are still in sorted order.

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions of Excel that uses Ribbons: Select Home, Editing. Click on the drop-down next to Sort & Filtering. Click Clear

[image]

Comment: This doesn't revert the sort, it just clears the filter.

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your file on the top of the Excel application shows "[Group]," then you might want to unselect to only the a single sheet on the bottom of tabs.  Then try the unfilter.

Answer (score -2):

If you have the date column in this sheet. You can clear the filter from the column where you want to undo sorting and come to date column and select sorting option to sort the dates from oldest to newest or newest to oldest to solve the issue.